# Is a Stack Exchange University site plausible?

Tags: discussion

No idea what to call/label it, but with all of the experts on the various SE sites there are bound to be opportunities for experts to teach an online course through "webex presentation", video/chat/peer group work, handouts, etc.  Courses that can be quick and concise covering a specific topic or sub-topic, not 5 day courses.

I know there are plenty of "learn to program" sites out there, but that doesn't encompass all the various subsites and aspects of the SE network.  Topics that could be worthy of a webinar or other andragogical teaching methods could be presented live or recorded and posted for offline viewing/study.

Even if the presentations, etc. are simply links to offsite relevant webinars, etc. that are offered free and categorized and groomed for expertise, content, relevance.  We could then rate them or review them on a site here where others could quickly see "man, this must be a good webinar to go watch on this topic."

Possible topics could be all over the board but only based on/linked to existing SE sites, and with categories/tags and sorting one could easily weed out the good and the bad.  Upvoting/downvoting could also occur as well as site moderation for obvious spam or crap.

Thoughts?  Suggested before?  I know it doesn't fit the SE Q&A model so it would have to be something new/different like Discourse.org is trying to accomplish.

Comment: So, you are suggesting some new model that isn't the SE model?

Comment: @Oded - I'm suggesting something that could belong in parallel to the SE network of sites.  I know it wouldn't operate on a Q&A model.  But posting this here in Meta.SO is the only place to offer such a suggestion to garner feedback, otherwise I could've sent an email to the StackExchange folks directly as a suggestion for them.

Comment: I think 99% of people here, including the professionals, have full time day jobs in the profession they help out with here. So teaching would likely not be an option. Videos might work, however, but is completely away from the Q&A as you said. And as technology changes it would be quite a bit to maintain them to remain the high quality they would need to be to earn the Stack name... It's a nice idea, however...

Comment: Sure. But what we do at SE is... Q&A sites. What you are proposing is extremely different. It is far away enough that it would require a different organisation to manage it. However much merit the idea may have - it just isn't something I can see us doing.

Comment: Programmers.SE sort of does this by soliciting well-written posts for [their blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/).  The problem as I see it is not so much a software problem as it is a time problem.  How much time and energy do people have to submit teachings?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Time to expand to a [vlog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_blog)?

Comment: @oded: That seems like a reasonable step.  It would be nice to be able to inline videos on the blog posts, YouTube style.

Comment: Yikes. Videos take a lot of work and are difficult to find information in quickly.

Comment: Thats why there exist transcriptions @minitech

Comment: Yes. Except sometimes they don’t. @AsheeshR

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/ - seriously, if you're interested in this sort of thing, check it out.

Comment: They have an absurdly large number of Ben's working for them...

Answer (score 4):

We all want free high quality content which has been vetted and curated by someone we trust. Most of us would also like high paying jobs where we can choose our work. I think this recommendation pretty much falls into the realm of fantasy - easy to imagine, troublesome to implement.

The problems, as excellently laid out by psubsee2003, are numerous:

- The curation process for lecture-type content is laborious. It may take 10 minutes or even hours to get through a single "post" just to see what was contained within - never mind the effort required to research "red flags" and to endlessly debate whether `goto` should really be covered in a beginner course. Very few people are able or willing to dedicated that sort of time with absolutely no prospect of compensation.
- Of those who have the time to review a presentation, most would probably be "newbies" (the target audience). Thus, most of those who view the entire presentation would, almost by definition, *not* be qualified to judge it fairly or to critique subtle but potentially harmful flaws.
- Unlike a *real* college, it would be nearly impossible to vet individuals before they begin posting content. The SE model is built around content, not individuals, and curates content *after* it has been posted, not before. Given the above two points, you'd easily end up with a site stuffed to the brim with bad advice, incomplete content and thousands of presentations almost exactly duplicating one another. Who needs a site with 500 lectures covering the basics of object-orientation, half of which have 0 stars and 0 votes?

The idea certainly caught my interest, but in the end I'd have to vote "no" on this one - it would pull resources away from Stack Exchange but I can't see it bearing much fruit.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a webex or similar is an interesting one -- I'd say the best way to handle it is for the individual communities to organize them, and then toss the recording on the site's blog.

That should reach the widest interested audience, and having the recordings on the site blog (along with a text summary/discussion) gives a good resource to point people at.

The only downside I see is finding time to actually *do* the seminars/recordings :-)

Comment: And that's a heck of a downside. Even *writing* a decent tutorial takes a fair bit of effort; producing a video tutorial - a good one at least - is a rather more substantial undertaking.

Comment: I wouldn't approach it as a "tutorial" so much as either a seminar or a panel discussion -- still you're right: It takes a ***huge*** amount of time. The reason I haven't done any conference presentations in the last few years is by the time I can put something decent together someone else has already said everything I wanted to say...

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting about the deviation from the normal Q&A model, let's look at some of the other issues, specifically who would decide what gets published and by who?

- Would presenters have to have specific expertise?
- Who would be the judge of that expertise?
- Would it be by SO reputation (or the reputation of the SE site that would host the content)
- What if a real-life expert without any rep wanted to write something?

These are the problems you run into any community like this where "expertise" is based on some artificial number.  Many of the highest members are indeed experts or key contributors to the actual technologies, but similarly, high rep users could be nothing but experts in the SE model and not really be worth learning from.  Likewise, there are many experts who are no active.  This would bar them from participating or at least force someone to have to vouch for someone else's expertise in specific fields.  So using rep as a guideline would not work.

Likewise just opening up to anyone would be a bad idea too.  If SE is going to be hosting "presentations by experts", then they are putting their own reputation (and not the unicorn dollars - real world reputation) on the line for host a webinar by someone who is showing a specific technique that ends up being vulnerable to SQL injection, for example.

Comment: I agree with your points and don't have all the answers.  Something like voretaq is suggesting could work as well.    My intent is not to foster a crapfest of 2 minute youtube videos with poor video/audio/content.  But if I can find various learning materials that I know the SE sites trust (via upvote/moderation/whatever) then I can be better informed as to what learning content to view/read as opposed to hoping that an online webinar isn't just a sales pitch or poorly done or worse sketchy or amateur (like your SQL injection possibility)

Comment: @TheCleaner it could indeed be interesting, but how to manage it would be key to determining if it would be successful

Comment: `Who would be the judge of that expertise?` -- Presumably the community members already handling a site's "side-channel" (blog) content.  Whether or not those community members are *qualified* to do so is a question that I'll leave to the individual communities...

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea because based on the recent blog post https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/

This should be what this site should all be about

> *It is by programmers, for programmers, **with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world**. No matter what programming language you use, or what operating system you call home. Better programming is our goal. (from Introducing Stack Overflow, emphasis added)*

It's only logical that a *possible* avenue for Joel and Stack Exchange Inc. to look into next is full out (at least initially) programming education through classes (if the existing knowledge platforms aren't sufficient) then the rest of the SE network.

Jeff and Joel saw that forums weren't adequate, so they set out to solve that with a Q&A platform.

*Why be so myopic about branching out from just Q&A* if the point is to increase knowledge around the world?

Content wise, the feature-request on its own lack depth and content (for starters, who can we trust to teach) so it should have been initially introduced as a discussion.

Comment: I think there's a place for text-based tutorials, particularly in areas where information is traditionally lacking. Of course, hosting and curating this sort of thing has been CodeProject's core mission for a long time - so the real question is, can we do this *better* than what's already out there? If so, *how?*

Comment: @Shog9 - I think there comes a point when anonymous curation simply breaks down (that point being, in my estimate, around 5-20 minutes of applied concentration). Beyond that point, you probably need a vetted (and paid) group of individuals to whom you entrust the often dull and tedious task of picking through the refuse to find the rare gem. You then live with their efforts or, if unhappy with the quality of the content, get a new group of people and start over. At a certain level, there is simply no feasible replacement for a good college or university.